# onehot encoder in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, one-hot-encoding

I would like to index the maximum value (onehot encoder) of an instance of inputs in the keras model. I know how to preprocess it but I would like to execute it in the model.

```
inputs = [[ 1,2,3,5],
          [ 2,4,6,3],
          [ 0,7,1,2]]
argmax =[3,2,1]
onehot = [[0,0,0,1],
          [0,0,1,0],
          [0,1,0,0]]
concated= [[ 1,2,3,5, 0,0,0,1],
           [ 2,4,6,3, 0,0,1,0],
           [ 0,7,1,2, 0,1,0,0]]

inputs = Input()
argmax = K.argmax(inputs, axis=-1)
onehot = #How to perform this operation with keras ??#
concated = Concat([inputs,onehot], axis=-1)
```

EDITED
Would it be possible something like that code in python?

```
argmax = [3,2,1]
eye = np.eye(4)
eye[argmax]
Out[6]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[
                 [ 1,2,3,5],
                 [ 2,4,6,3],
                 [ 0,7,1,2]],
                 [
                 [ 9,2,3,5],
                 [ 2,2,2,3],
                 [ 0,1,5,2]]
                 ])


inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((3, 4))
argmax = tf.argmax(inputs, axis=-1)
ij = tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(
    tf.range(tf.shape(inputs)[0], dtype=tf.int64), 
    tf.range(tf.shape(inputs)[1], dtype=tf.int64),
                              indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
gather_indices = tf.concat([ij, tf.expand_dims(argmax, axis=-1)], axis=-1)

onehot = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tf.zeros_like(x, dtype=tf.float32), gather_indices, tf.ones_like(argmax, dtype=tf.float32))

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([inputs,onehot])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
print(model(x))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[1. 2. 3. 5. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [2. 4. 6. 3. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 7. 1. 2. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

 [[9. 2. 3. 5. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [2. 2. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 1. 5. 2. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]], shape=(2, 3, 8), dtype=float32)
```

An explanation to what `tf.meshgrid` is and why it is needed can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897393/get-values-from-tensor-using-argmax/69898146#69898146). You can consider wrapping these operations in a custom `Keras` layer.

If you would use `tf.reduce_max` instead of `tf.argmax`, it would be way simpler:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[
                 [ 1,2,3,5],
                 [ 2,4,6,3],
                 [ 0,7,1,2]],
                 [
                 [ 9,2,3,5],
                 [ 2,2,2,3],
                 [ 0,1,5,2]]
                 ])


inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((3, 4))
onehot = tf.where(tf.not_equal(inputs, tf.reduce_max(inputs, keepdims=True, axis=-1)), tf.zeros_like(inputs), tf.ones_like(inputs))

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([inputs,onehot])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
print(model(x))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[1. 2. 3. 5. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [2. 4. 6. 3. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 7. 1. 2. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

 [[9. 2. 3. 5. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [2. 2. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 1. 5. 2. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]], shape=(2, 3, 8), dtype=float32)
```

But I guess there is a reason you want to use `argmax`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems it works. Please check the EDIT I added so it would be easier if numpy like could apply...